# Loop through an array inside an object javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, loops

I have this javascript object children with multiple array inside and the array names are random.

[image]

how can i loop through it without specifying 'S801', 'S901' etc so i can get some result like

[52.4655012, 13.2595648], [21.1006158, 79.0074763] , ......

Comment: Please do not post images of code? Instead, provide a text-based [mcve]. -- Also take a look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and use the most appropriate one?

Comment: You can loop over objects with [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: Try doing `for (const key in myobject.children) { console.log(myobject.children[key]) } `

Comment: Thanks @AlexSp3 your method works too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Object.values` to get the values in the Object and then map over it.

```js
const obj = {
  children: {
    S801: [52, 13],
    S901: [21, 79]
  }
};

Object.values(obj.children).map(([value1,value2]) => {
  console.log(value1,value2)
})
```